# Why the child routes won't show in IONIC/Angular?

Tags: angular, routes, ionic4

I want to create a single navbar for a multiple pages website using IONIC/Angular.
The problem here is that the content written in order.page.html, which is a children of navbar.page, won't show up, even if I want to print something from order.page.ts, nothing is printed.
This code below should be enough to detect where is the problem.

navbar-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NavbarPage } from './navbar.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: NavbarPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'order',
        loadChildren: () => import('../order/order.module').then( m => m.OrderPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'order',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
})
export class NavbarPageRoutingModule {}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./navbar/navbar.module').then( m => m.NavbarPageModule)
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add router-outlet in the html part that's why